# How can I bind the selected text of a Select box to an object's attribute with Knockout JS, or anything else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, knockout.js

I have a select box pull down that I'm populating with a JSON list returned from a stored procedure, but unfortunately when I update the linked object I need to return the selected **text** of the pulldown, **not** the selected index like one would think (poor database design, but I'm stuck with it for now and cannot change it).

Does anyone have any ideas what I can do to keep the **selected text** synced with the appropriate javascript object's attribute?

Comment: Can't you create the <option>s for the select box with the values you need?

Comment: I'm already doing that, but the problem is I need to sync the a javascript object attribute with the selected TEXT (not index) of the select box. Wait: I think I see what you're saying now. Use the text for the index instead of the index... right?  I'll try that.

Comment: Damn, I hope it's just that easy...

Comment: Crap! Good call, @Endophage. I couldn't see the forest for the trees. Write this up as an answer and I'll cred you for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes, you got what I was getting at.  Use the text as the value for the select options rather than using an index.  The value really should be something useful, I can't think of any case where I've ever used an index.  A number sure, but a number that relates to the application's models in some way (like an id from a database), not to the number of items in the select box.

Well done.

Comment: You get the points, but I would still like to know if there's a way to have both. I can think of some cases where I'd like to have an object with some 'selectedIndex' and 'selectedText' values in it... and I'm not tied to KnockoutJS so I'm open to anything.

Comment: Try this: document.getElementById('id_of_selectbox').selectedIndex; It should work if you get to the select dom node through other method as well (jQuery's $(...) for example).

Answer (score 2):

You could keep both, the value and the text, if you use subscribers. 
For instance, if each of your javascript objects look like this:

```
    var optionObject = {
       text:"text1"
       value: 1
    }
```

Then your binding would look like:

Where 'OptionsObjects' is a collection of optionObject and selectedOption
has two observable properties: text and value.
Finally you subscribe to the value property of the selectedOption:

```
    viewModel.selectedOption.value.subscribe(function(newValue){
        var optionText = viewModel.OptionsObjects[newValue].text;
        viewModel.selectedOption.text(optionText);
    });
```

Then if you want to see the new selected option text when the value is changed,
you could have a binding as follows:

```
    <span data-bind:"text:selectedOption.text"></span>
```

In your particular case you would return selectedOption.text().